# dbIds from the Forge Viewer and the Model Derivative API are different

Tags: autodesk-forge, forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I'm working on creating a forge viewer-based web system linking with my client's BIM360 environment. For the model data extraction part, I refered to the examples below.

(1) https://github.com/xiaodongliang/forgeviewer_embed_in_powerbi_report/tree/master/forge-model-properties-excel 
(2) https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/bim360appstore-model.derivative-nodejs-xls.exporter

However, I realized that the dbIds from the Forge Viewer and the sample codes are different. Is this the reason because of the SVF version discrepancies (i.e., SVF1 vs. SVF2)? If yes, any suggestion to resolve it?

Moreover, some models were not correctly processed when I tried to extract model data using the second example code (i.e., ForgeXLS.js example). The code was not processed after calling "prepareTables" function. It seems like it has issues to conduct "getMetadata", "getHierarchy", and "getProperties" functions. Could you let me know some possible reasons?

Answer (score 0):

*SVF version discrepancies*

yes, the dbId of SVF is not consistent in all versions of the model. SVF2 dbId can be same in different versions, but the ideal is to take advantage of external id of the object. i.e. build a map from the first version of the model with external id. When you want to use dbId, search the dbId by external id

*extract model data using the second example code (i.e., ForgeXLS.js example)*

I'd believe it is just because the metadata / properties of the model version sis too large. you may try to add the header **forceget**  when fetching the properties
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET/